# Unchecking All checkboxes

Tags: jquery

The checkAll click function works, however, the uncheckAll click function does not. Anybody see what is preventing it from unchecking all the checkboxes that are checked.

```
$('#checkAll').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id','uncheckAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('Uncheck All Checkboxes');
});

$('#uncheckAll').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id','checkAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('Check All Checkboxes');
});
```

EDIT:

I tried this however for some reason it doesn't do anything. Not sure why.

```
$('#dataTablePageList').delegate('#checkAll', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked',true);
    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id','uncheckAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('Uncheck All Checkboxes');
});

$('#dataTablePageList').delegate('#uncheckAll', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id','checkAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('Check All Checkboxes');
});
```

Edit 3:

```
$('#viewAll').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(-1);
    $(this).removeClass('viewAll').addClass('paginateRecords');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View Paginated Records');
    $('.pagination').hide();
}); 

$('#paginateRecords').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(10);
    $(this).removeClass('paginateRecords').addClass('viewAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View All Records'); 
    $('.pagination').show();          
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event `click` is binded to DOM element, not every css-match now-or-in-future, so on the first run, only `#checkAll` would be binded, and latter would not be used at all

try another way - by using toggle on check element

```
$('#checkAll').toggle(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    $(this).find('strong').html('Uncheck All Checkboxes');
},function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    $(this).find('strong').html('Check All Checkboxes');
});
```

as for edit3:

```
$('#viewAll').toggle(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(-1);
    $(this).find('strong').html('View Paginated Records');
    $('.pagination').hide();
}, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(10);
    $(this).find('strong').html('View All Records'); 
    $('.pagination').show();          
});
```

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) take as parameters two functions which are run alternately after subsequent clicks

Comment: consider changing approach, using delegate to that is sooo ugly

Comment: I don't know its just my lack of experience and trying to get things to work. What should I do?

Comment: sorry, I now understand what do you want, added ^, it's the same as previous one

Comment: I'm coming up with some odd sitiuations that even prevent the view all and toggle to work so give me a min to create a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfS4H/1/  Trying to find out why the jquery and stuff isn't working right. But that's not the main issue. The main issue is for the checkAll and uncheckAll should only do their tasks for on the current pagination page. Because one issue I was having is I was checking all checkboxes and going to another page and the buttons ids are getting messed up when the page change.

Comment: hard to understand. as for handling many .pagination - use $(this).parents('.pagination').hide(); or something like that

Comment: I did away with the part of hiding and showing the pagination.

Comment: Still not sure why its not showing only the first 10 rows that way I can get to the bottom of the actual problem.

Comment: But do you know about what I put in my reply with the new jsfiddle. About the new issue.

Comment: put important (and only that) code inside jsfiddle not on external scripts, describe showcase - what do you expect and what is happeining instead, is it happeing on jsfiddle or in your private code? but unfortunately I have to go now, maybe later I would look into that

Comment: Is there a chance I can get you to email me so I can show you login credentials for my CMS so you can see the live version of this script because for some reason when I mess wiht jsfiddle its not wanting to cooperate with what I'm trying to show. My email is xtremer360@yahoo.com

Comment: @Jacek_FH let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2190/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-jacek-fh)

Comment: Were you able to see the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
$(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id','uncheckAll');
```

When you say this:

```
$('#uncheckAll').click(function (e) { ...
```

You're binding a callback function to the element with an `id` of `uncheckAll` **at the time when `.click` is called**; when you change the `id`, you're not changing the callbacks that are already bound. You could switch to using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) for binding your `click` event or (better IMHO) use two separate buttons and hide/show them as needed:

Answer (score 1):

this simple line should uncheck all checkboxes:

```
$('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

and this one will check all:

```
$('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

I don't see a reason to change the ids of the "checkAll/uncheckAll" element in order to accomplish what you want.

just have something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='toggleAll' onclick="toggleAll(this);" />

function toggleAll(element){

  $('#dataTablePageList :checkbox').attr('checked',element.checked);
}
```

[Look at this quick example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6GUmQ/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using live() instead of click(), since you are getting rid of/resetting the id you have bound the action to, live() may work better.